# How to tidy messy corners generated by solidify modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I use a mesh with cross section like **1** as input to `solidify` modifier, and I expect to have a result like **2**. However, it gave me messy results in corner parts like **3**. How can I tidy the messy corner in some simple way? Currently I made a self-crossover cut and manually remove the messy faces, which is pretty much work.

[image]

And this is the snapshot of actual result. I hide the outer shell and most flat parts of the inner shell, only showing the corner part to ease the editing procedure.

[image]

Comment: With this kind of topology you are lucky if you got the issue only in corner part ...

Answer (score 1):

There is not any magic way to avoid the overlapping, even with a new complex *Solidify Modifier* (if I'm not mistaken).

[image]

When *Solidify* modifier was set to **Complex** mode with *Thickness* mode **Fixed**, you can try ...

### Weld Modifier

It worked with small distances, but already here it started to change outer topology.

[image]

With higher value of Thickness ...

[image]

... you would have to apply *Solidify* modifier, select inner vertex and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select *Linked* and assign those to *Vertex Group* under *Data Properties*.

[image]

Than use this vertex group as a limit for modifier.

[image]

### Remesh Modifier

But ... this *Weld* works only because of the big flat faces inside. Probably useless in your situation. You will probably more lucky with *Remesh* modifier > **Voxel** type.